# Transfer onenote notebook between online accounts???

Tags: microsoft-onenote, outlook.com

I have an account online (normal outlook.com) where I have a notebook in onenote with alot of important info that I want to move to another online account so i can use it with "onenote online" there instead on the new account. (Im changing account). But how do I do that? To much to copy & paste manually with all formatting and stuff so need to backup it in some way so I can use it on the new accout.

I have tested to download the notebook file from onedrive from the first account and uploaded it to the second account and it show up as an onenote notebook but when I try to open it in "onenote online" from onedrive, it say the file dont exist or I dont have permission to view it.
But i

cant see any way in "onenote online" to export or something like that, the notebook without any "restriction".

If I cant transfer an onenote notebook in any way from one online account to another "directly" by just moving a file.

Is it possible to do that via "onenote 2013" on the computer instead? How do I do that in that case? Any suggestion to test would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is via the OneNote client for Windows which is the most mature of the clients.

This is made even easier if you can access the new network location from Windows Explorer since OneNode has a "Change location" button on the Notebook Properties. Use this from the original location to move it to your local PC. Then use it again once you have the new location sync'd up.

Otherwise open a new notebook in the new location and the old one and move each tab by right-clicking and "Move...".